# how can VB.NET Web App project compile .vb files that are in a VB.NET Windows App project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, azure

How can my frontend VB.NET WEB APP project build from common .vb files that are in my backend VB.NET WINDOWS APP?

Up to now, I've maintained two copies of these common .vb files; one copy in the backend windows app project, and the other copy in the frontend web app project.

This obviously is messy, since I need to merge changes, which wastes time.

I want the backend common files to be the 'master' copy, and want to know how the frontend web app project can access (or, 'link to') these common files in the backend.  This way, any change to the common files is used by both my web and windows app.

If I have the web app project add the files in the windows app project, it actually copies the files into the web app project's folder.

(The web app is the user interface, and the windows app runs continuously in the background performing the calendar time based functions that the web app cannot.)

PLATFORMS:
VS 2015 Community on Azure

Comment: Create a class library type project, move your common classes/files to that project and then reference that project in your other projects. The output of class library will be a "dll"

Comment: I need to share the source, so that I can alter it when I debug.  Sharing a debug will take a lot more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use project > Add existing > Add command > drop down next to Add button > Add as Link in drop down

NOTE:  Some versions of ASP.NET have bug where Add as Link not available.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the shared files into a .dll is probably the right way to go.  However, if you have some reason why you really don't want to refactor these files into a separate assembly, you could use the Add As Link feature in Visual Studio.  Right-click in you Web App source file folder, and choose "Add\Existing Item".  Then navigate to the Windows App folder, and select the file(s) you want to copy over.  Instead of clicking the "Add" button, click the small dropdown arrow next to that button, and choose "Add As Link".  This will create a link in the Web App project to the files that actually reside in the Windows App.

Comment: Add/Existing Item navigation to Windows App folder doesn't show any .vb files.  So I type "*.vb" in the File name text box, select my common .vb files, but there is only at Add button, to Add As Link.  Do I need VS 2015 Pro?  I'm using VS 2015 Community.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise, so it's possible, but double-check.  Do you not see a small black arrow next to the "Add" button?  If so, click it, and a dropdown menu will appear.

Comment: No. I opened VB.NET Web app project (little globe to left of project name under Solution > right clicked > chose Add As Link > no Add drop down > selected files > still no Add drop down.  Moral of the story:  you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access that code from another project?

If so, make the project you want to access into a DLL project, then add it as a reference in the other project.

Make sure to make what you want to access public or at least over internal in acessibility

Comment: Yes.   I think cranking out a 3rd project for .DLL and modifying and re-building that project every time I change common source code will waste too much time.  I want change common source while debugging either web and windows app, then simply rebuild the other project.